# element.scrollTop always returns 0

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to get the scrollTop position of an element, but it always returns 0. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

#### JSFiddle

```js
var inner = document.getElementById('inner');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  console.log(inner.scrollTop);
})
```

```css
#outer {
  background-color: tan;
  height: 1000px;
}
#first {
  background-color: bisque;
  height: 200px;
}
#inner {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="first"></div>
  <div id="inner">scrollTop always returns 0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop): *"The Element.scrollTop property gets or sets the number of pixels that the content of an element is scrolled upward. An element's scrollTop is a form of distance measurement regarding an element's top to its topmost visible content. When an element content does not generate a vertical scrollbar, then its scrollTop value defaults to 0."* Since the content of `inner` doesn't generate a scrollbar, `scrollTop` is `0`. In other words: `scrollTop` is not the property you are looking for.

Comment: @FelixKling Oh. I get it! Thanks! So how can I check its scrollTop based on `window` (or the scroll element)?

Comment: `inner.offsetTop - window.scrollY` would work in this case, but I don't know if that's the best way.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As @FelixKling pointed out in the comments:

`inner.offsetTop` is what to use for this. [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) returns the amount you **scrolled** in that particular container. So because `inner` doesn't have a scrollbar, it never scrolls, and therefore `scrollTop` is 0.

But [`offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop), on the other hand, returns the distance of the current element relative to the top of the `offsetParent` node.

So the formula to get the amount scrolled of an element **based** on `window`, would be:

```
inner.offsetTop - document.body.scrollTop;
```

Answer (score 16):

For some reason, removing 'height: 100%' from my html and body tags fixed this issue.

I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: THANK YOU! I had a #content-container div for the page with a "height: 100vh" that was doing it on mine.

Comment: @ShaneMcCurdy perfect, I had to remove this from a CSS that was applied to my root element. Found it with VSCode project-wide search for "100vh"

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure why, but the only thing I could get to work was using `window.pageYOffset`:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
  if (scrollPosition >= 30) {
    headerContainer.classList.add('lg:bg-green-lightest');
  } else {
    headerContainer.classList.remove('lg:bg-green-lightest');
  }
});
```

Comment: This is the first thing that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Removing `overflow: hidden` from my html tag fixed this for me.

Answer (score -1):

I found a simplest way to do this by adding eventListener to window object this way:

```
window.addEventListener("click", () => {
     let value = window.scrollTop;
     console.log(value);
});
```

This isn't the cleanest way, but It's the only way I got it work as it should.