# How to get scroll position of an element when window is not scrollable and scrollbar is hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, uiscrollview

### Setup

On scrolling, the content behind navbar is still visible, I want it to be invisible while still looking clean.

[image: the design]

---

### Attempt #1

A rect. div behind the navbar does the trick of hiding content below it, but notice when the text appears (The inception) the pink div is still visible behind navbar (I want to change it to white when scrolled in view)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: initial;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(252, 241, 239);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

#mobile_size {
  width: 550px;
  height: 650px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 3%;
  position: relative;
}

#mobile_screen {
  width: 530px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: rgb(252, 241, 239);
  border-radius: 3%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  left: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(252, 248, 248);
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 10px rgb(0, 0, 0, .13);
  z-index: 3;
}

#gradient_pink {
  background: rgb(237, 218, 218);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(237, 218, 218, 1) 0%, rgba(252, 241, 239, 1) 21%);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  width: 140%;
  height: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#gradient_white {
  background-color: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  width: 140%;
  height: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

h1:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  margin-right: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul,
li {
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline;
  margin: 5px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#img_gallery {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(252, 241, 239);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 500px;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 480px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

#about_company {
  margin-top: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  height: auto;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

p {
  padding: 60px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-align: justify;
}

#ig_container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(250, 236, 233);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 500px;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <title>Jino</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mobile_size">
    <div id="mobile_screen">
       <div id="gradient_pink"></div>
       <!-- <div id="gradient_white"></div> -->
      <header>
        <h1 id="name">JINO</h1>
        <ul>
          <a href="#">
            <li>ABOUT</li>
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <li>CONTACT</li>
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <li>SERVICES</li>
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <li>SHOP</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </header>
      <main>
        <div id="ig_container">
          <div id="img_gallery">
            <img src='http://unsplash.it/g/501?random&gravity=center' alt='' />
            <img src='http://unsplash.it/g/502?random&gravity=center' alt='' />
            <img src='http://unsplash.it/g/503?random&gravity=center' alt='' />
            <img src='http://unsplash.it/g/504?random&gravity=center' alt='' />
            <img src='http://unsplash.it/g/505?random&gravity=center' alt='' />
            <img src='http://unsplash.it/g/506?random&gravity=center' alt='' />
            <img src='http://unsplash.it/g/507?random&gravity=center' alt='' />
            <img src='http://unsplash.it/g/500?random&gravity=center' alt='' />

          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="about_company">
          <h3>THE INCEPTION</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam minus maiores, veritatis fugiat ut, perspiciatis corrupti, nam eius provident molestias nesciunt fuga! Veritatis temporibus tempore dolor est rerum doloribus, qui voluptatibus id
            veniam. Ipsa architecto eligendi hic fugiat minima at laboriosam sapiente animi nostrum amet minus maiores distinctio quasi est tempore nisi similique voluptate doloremque excepturi, tenetur, eius mollitia! Non, soluta? Culpa dicta quisquam
            saepe non. Quis ea dolores amet modi magnam maiores porro consequuntur debitis at ex hic necessitatibus minus sunt excepturi quo quasi sed, expedita, sit cupiditate! Tenetur ipsam impedit, sit vel ab velit esse temporibus magnam. Cumque ab
            quos enim nostrum error, dicta tenetur distinctio repellendus quasi facere labore culpa qui eos dolore, cum, ut atque explicabo alias totam? Nesciunt illum incidunt dignissimos. Illum laudantium neque aliquam, sequi odio laboriosam beatae
            in enim nulla nostrum tenetur necessitatibus ullam illo perferendis adipisci possimus sapiente nemo. Doloribus iste ipsa voluptates cum reprehenderit officia, nemo totam repudiandae eaque eveniet delectus. Optio dolore cum, nemo aspernatur
            qui mollitia aliquid officia architecto magnam delectus omnis accusamus velit esse natus molestiae. Modi, distinctio cumque nobis ducimus accusamus quo neque aperiam, tenetur reprehenderit incidunt fugit quaerat provident totam quos! Magni
            molestias aut alias exercitationem repellendus ut eum et nesciunt ullam corporis illo veniam, laudantium sed quod veritatis velit adipisci sint accusantium vel. Delectus corporis fugiat aperiam dicta accusantium tempore adipisci praesentium
            voluptas fuga ex. Porro tenetur consequuntur in ipsa cum, numquam iure, facilis ipsam, dignissimos est rerum voluptates eveniet dolor dolorum itaque perspiciatis veniam. Inventore incidunt mollitia delectus iste eligendi tempore aut ex provident
            error suscipit, adipisci magnam cupiditate hic quis rerum pariatur vitae magni corrupti veritatis assumenda dolore atque, praesentium consequatur quasi. Vitae aperiam nulla minima omnis explicabo. Quibusdam, vel? Consequuntur vitae debitis
            accusamus accusantium assumenda magni nobis, labore iure illum inventore eaque ullam totam. Praesentium, incidunt! Quisquam itaque ut tenetur nostrum non ratione, consectetur sunt quas ducimus saepe fugit deserunt, ad assumenda! Sit possimus
            minima fugiat accusamus pariatur, voluptates impedit sapiente nam vel cumque, odio rem natus, tempore consequatur eveniet reiciendis adipisci doloremque dolorum voluptatibus totam amet ab. Ad, minus? Quaerat ratione possimus numquam veniam
            fugit. Iure tempora delectus deserunt. Hic nisi sed soluta itaque adipisci, facere voluptatibus nesciunt culpa earum deserunt iste magni laboriosam dignissimos blanditiis, ipsa laborum? Sapiente, sequi. Dicta cum debitis magni molestias odio
            praesentium temporibus voluptatum culpa qui adipisci expedita, quibusdam ad earum tenetur. Tenetur nulla impedit deleniti iusto numquam, dolorem doloribus aliquam molestiae vero aspernatur velit eos, reprehenderit accusamus enim magni quam
            in libero! Eligendi dolore, fuga placeat dicta aliquam aut laudantium, in temporibus, asperiores enim expedita voluptas alias quasi error harum? Cumque sequi porro labore, nisi minima molestiae tempora, voluptatum sit veniam omnis magnam deleniti
            esse dolorem expedita tempore eos totam quidem provident officiis vero culpa doloremque quasi delectus. Harum cumque velit dignissimos accusantium qui nesciunt consequuntur error quis sint tenetur et nisi recusandae similique aliquam, ea sapiente!
            Cum molestias tempore dolorum dolor ullam deleniti architecto distinctio aperiam rem eos! Illo, velit molestiae cum atque cumque vel repellat libero deleniti animi accusamus vitae! Iure, reiciendis. Explicabo suscipit modi incidunt perferendis
            earum unde reprehenderit quod rerum iste soluta, saepe nulla voluptas, voluptatum, tempora vero eius nisi iure culpa nesciunt distinctio. Dolorum possimus soluta nemo. Molestias odio at tempora hic labore eligendi dolorum beatae deleniti,
            est facilis nemo, dolore a ad. Doloribus itaque iure quos maiores quidem fugiat? Minus, nobis recusandae pariatur similique saepe repellendus impedit rerum veniam veritatis dolorem facere, laudantium itaque eligendi, magnam odio incidunt exercitationem
            sapiente asperiores quas? Quidem iste, pariatur blanditiis nostrum nobis earum officia eum laboriosam placeat, at voluptatum labore laborum neque ullam ipsum odit quod, reprehenderit autem sit doloremque recusandae quaerat! Ducimus quaerat
            totam eius facere. Iure, laborum vel sequi blanditiis veniam quaerat quia. Voluptate modi, cumque quam officia impedit harum, debitis delectus necessitatibus magni officiis culpa obcaecati. Debitis nemo sed eum ullam similique fugiat id, veritatis
            facere quidem delectus odit nulla dicta aperiam sint ab voluptatibus perspiciatis eos officiis. Doloribus, consequuntur error dicta repellat incidunt unde nemo, corrupti magnam architecto nulla ut similique saepe maxime culpa sit? Ducimus
            adipisci perferendis commodi. Voluptatibus quam sit, debitis odit recusandae cupiditate, asperiores nisi sint distinctio nulla autem possimus esse nostrum deserunt. Voluptatum nemo sint delectus consequatur, ipsum mollitia. Debitis aliquam
            consectetur repudiandae commodi ratione est sit inventore aliquid nam blanditiis aperiam distinctio doloremque nihil sed quae voluptatum cum modi, eveniet alias voluptas harum unde. Hic libero error eveniet saepe ab animi laborum adipisci
            magnam eos incidunt minus, odio molestiae. Debitis cum molestiae reiciendis ipsa. Error nemo ipsum eius explicabo accusantium dolore, voluptatibus et quos laboriosam maxime eum saepe. Exercitationem nam natus delectus placeat doloribus sunt
            consequatur autem sapiente. Architecto obcaecati quis reiciendis repellat recusandae sequi exercitationem rerum. Ipsa, mollitia. Ipsam, quas, officia voluptatibus repudiandae, eaque eos quis sit voluptas fugiat quae laudantium adipisci tempora
            ullam magnam dolorem delectus! Natus alias distinctio deserunt laboriosam placeat doloremque vel quis possimus, laudantium accusantium? Consectetur recusandae eaque voluptas eligendi modi vel ratione libero aperiam rem! Sint qui reprehenderit
            ut, adipisci tenetur minus cumque, iusto quam id quis harum exercitationem aspernatur sit rem eius nobis libero a nam animi laborum esse accusamus illo provident dolor. Repudiandae, aliquam. Et illum itaque eum beatae facilis nihil nam? Voluptatibus
            nesciunt veritatis voluptate facere autem molestiae ut similique deserunt eligendi odit! Eius error sit ut praesentium voluptate eum ullam modi architecto, sequi quae. Error obcaecati ducimus debitis ratione nam saepe omnis tempore excepturi
            natus ex exercitationem necessitatibus minus, minima a ipsa ad repellat placeat ipsam culpa sequi dicta. Ea rem tenetur quibusdam illum magni perferendis saepe quasi quisquam, odio amet adipisci, voluptate repellat voluptates impedit facilis
            expedita aliquam velit officiis! Nemo maxime illo sapiente omnis corporis iusto sunt similique enim beatae itaque quasi pariatur, voluptas impedit consequuntur ipsam iste delectus unde? Sunt, ipsam quasi. Debitis veniam laborum modi sequi
            accusantium ut fugit reprehenderit rem hic laudantium aperiam illo nulla odit officiis, saepe, architecto voluptas, nam eos iste aliquid vel! Vero dolorem nemo amet eaque fuga illum, sed fugiat, ullam quo iste facere voluptates!</p>
        </div>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: navbar with a div behind it]

---

### Possible method

Fetch the scroll position of text container element (the inception and lorem text) and hide/show divs with pink/white color.
But I am not able to fetch in the scroll position.
ScrollTop always return 0, I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391907/element-scrolltop-always-returns-0) but my window is not scrollable like the linked problem but the element inside it is.
I dont understand how to think about it, I am missing some key point.
Any links to articles or reads are welcomed.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the color to change but the contents not to be visible above (and to the side of??) the nav bar?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes.
I want the div (id : gradient_pink) to change color, when scrolled to a specific position, so that it blends with the white background in a clean way.

Comment: By 'clean' do you mean gradual?

Comment: @AHaworth By clean I mean "not noticeable". However it is applied.

Answer (score 0):

a partial answer,
you could get the height of `$("#ig_container") and compare it to scroll top distance.

my code does that but it still need some improvement for the smoothness you wanted.

```js
var positionReached = false;

$('#mobile_screen').scroll(function(e){
const scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
const containerHeight = $("#ig_container").height();

if(!positionReached && scrollPosition>= containerHeight){
    positionReached = true;
    $("#gradient_pink").css("background","white");
}else if(scrollPosition < containerHeight)
  if(positionReached){ 
      positionReached = false;
      $("#gradient_pink").css("background","rgb(237, 218, 218)");
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: initial;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(252, 241, 239);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

#mobile_size {
  width: 550px;
  height: 650px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 3%;
  position: relative;
}

#mobile_screen {
  width: 530px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: rgb(252, 241, 239);
  border-radius: 3%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  left: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(252, 248, 248);
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 10px rgb(0, 0, 0, .13);
  z-index: 3;
}

#gradient_pink {
  background: rgb(237, 218, 218);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(237, 218, 218, 1) 0%, rgba(252, 241, 239, 1) 21%);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  width: 140%;
  height: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#gradient_white {
  background-color: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  width: 140%;
  height: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

h1:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  margin-right: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul,
li {
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline;
  margin: 5px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#img_gallery {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(252, 241, 239);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 500px;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 480px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

#about_company {
  margin-top: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  height: auto;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

p {
  padding: 60px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-align: justify;
}

#ig_container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(250, 236, 233);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 500px;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <title>Jino</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mobile_size">
    <div id="mobile_screen">
       <div id="gradient_pink"></div>
       <!-- <div id="gradient_white"></div> -->
      <header>
        <h1 id="name">JINO</h1>
        <ul>
          <a href="#">
            <li>ABOUT</li>
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <li>CONTACT</li>
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <li>SERVICES</li>
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <li>SHOP</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </header>
      <main>
        <div id="ig_container">
          <div id="img_gallery">
            <img src='http://unsplash.it/g/501?random&gravity=center' alt='' />
            <img src='http://unsplash.it/g/502?random&gravity=center' alt='' />
            <img src='http://unsplash.it/g/503?random&gravity=center' alt='' />
            <img src='http://unsplash.it/g/504?random&gravity=center' alt='' />
            <img src='http://unsplash.it/g/505?random&gravity=center' alt='' />
            <img src='http://unsplash.it/g/506?random&gravity=center' alt='' />
            <img src='http://unsplash.it/g/507?random&gravity=center' alt='' />
            <img src='http://unsplash.it/g/500?random&gravity=center' alt='' />

          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="about_company">
          <h3>THE INCEPTION</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam minus maiores, veritatis fugiat ut, perspiciatis corrupti, nam eius provident molestias nesciunt fuga! Veritatis temporibus tempore dolor est rerum doloribus, qui voluptatibus id
            veniam. Ipsa architecto eligendi hic fugiat minima at laboriosam sapiente animi nostrum amet minus maiores distinctio quasi est tempore nisi similique voluptate doloremque excepturi, tenetur, eius mollitia! Non, soluta? Culpa dicta quisquam
            saepe non. Quis ea dolores amet modi magnam maiores porro consequuntur debitis at ex hic necessitatibus minus sunt excepturi quo quasi sed, expedita, sit cupiditate! Tenetur ipsam impedit, sit vel ab velit esse temporibus magnam. Cumque ab
            quos enim nostrum error, dicta tenetur distinctio repellendus quasi facere labore culpa qui eos dolore, cum, ut atque explicabo alias totam? Nesciunt illum incidunt dignissimos. Illum laudantium neque aliquam, sequi odio laboriosam beatae
            in enim nulla nostrum tenetur necessitatibus ullam illo perferendis adipisci possimus sapiente nemo. Doloribus iste ipsa voluptates cum reprehenderit officia, nemo totam repudiandae eaque eveniet delectus. Optio dolore cum, nemo aspernatur
            qui mollitia aliquid officia architecto magnam delectus omnis accusamus velit esse natus molestiae. Modi, distinctio cumque nobis ducimus accusamus quo neque aperiam, tenetur reprehenderit incidunt fugit quaerat provident totam quos! Magni
            molestias aut alias exercitationem repellendus ut eum et nesciunt ullam corporis illo veniam, laudantium sed quod veritatis velit adipisci sint accusantium vel. Delectus corporis fugiat aperiam dicta accusantium tempore adipisci praesentium
            voluptas fuga ex. Porro tenetur consequuntur in ipsa cum, numquam iure, facilis ipsam, dignissimos est rerum voluptates eveniet dolor dolorum itaque perspiciatis veniam. Inventore incidunt mollitia delectus iste eligendi tempore aut ex provident
            error suscipit, adipisci magnam cupiditate hic quis rerum pariatur vitae magni corrupti veritatis assumenda dolore atque, praesentium consequatur quasi. Vitae aperiam nulla minima omnis explicabo. Quibusdam, vel? Consequuntur vitae debitis
            accusamus accusantium assumenda magni nobis, labore iure illum inventore eaque ullam totam. Praesentium, incidunt! Quisquam itaque ut tenetur nostrum non ratione, consectetur sunt quas ducimus saepe fugit deserunt, ad assumenda! Sit possimus
            minima fugiat accusamus pariatur, voluptates impedit sapiente nam vel cumque, odio rem natus, tempore consequatur eveniet reiciendis adipisci doloremque dolorum voluptatibus totam amet ab. Ad, minus? Quaerat ratione possimus numquam veniam
            fugit. Iure tempora delectus deserunt. Hic nisi sed soluta itaque adipisci, facere voluptatibus nesciunt culpa earum deserunt iste magni laboriosam dignissimos blanditiis, ipsa laborum? Sapiente, sequi. Dicta cum debitis magni molestias odio
            praesentium temporibus voluptatum culpa qui adipisci expedita, quibusdam ad earum tenetur. Tenetur nulla impedit deleniti iusto numquam, dolorem doloribus aliquam molestiae vero aspernatur velit eos, reprehenderit accusamus enim magni quam
            in libero! Eligendi dolore, fuga placeat dicta aliquam aut laudantium, in temporibus, asperiores enim expedita voluptas alias quasi error harum? Cumque sequi porro labore, nisi minima molestiae tempora, voluptatum sit veniam omnis magnam deleniti
            esse dolorem expedita tempore eos totam quidem provident officiis vero culpa doloremque quasi delectus. Harum cumque velit dignissimos accusantium qui nesciunt consequuntur error quis sint tenetur et nisi recusandae similique aliquam, ea sapiente!
            Cum molestias tempore dolorum dolor ullam deleniti architecto distinctio aperiam rem eos! Illo, velit molestiae cum atque cumque vel repellat libero deleniti animi accusamus vitae! Iure, reiciendis. Explicabo suscipit modi incidunt perferendis
            earum unde reprehenderit quod rerum iste soluta, saepe nulla voluptas, voluptatum, tempora vero eius nisi iure culpa nesciunt distinctio. Dolorum possimus soluta nemo. Molestias odio at tempora hic labore eligendi dolorum beatae deleniti,
            est facilis nemo, dolore a ad. Doloribus itaque iure quos maiores quidem fugiat? Minus, nobis recusandae pariatur similique saepe repellendus impedit rerum veniam veritatis dolorem facere, laudantium itaque eligendi, magnam odio incidunt exercitationem
            sapiente asperiores quas? Quidem iste, pariatur blanditiis nostrum nobis earum officia eum laboriosam placeat, at voluptatum labore laborum neque ullam ipsum odit quod, reprehenderit autem sit doloremque recusandae quaerat! Ducimus quaerat
            totam eius facere. Iure, laborum vel sequi blanditiis veniam quaerat quia. Voluptate modi, cumque quam officia impedit harum, debitis delectus necessitatibus magni officiis culpa obcaecati. Debitis nemo sed eum ullam similique fugiat id, veritatis
            facere quidem delectus odit nulla dicta aperiam sint ab voluptatibus perspiciatis eos officiis. Doloribus, consequuntur error dicta repellat incidunt unde nemo, corrupti magnam architecto nulla ut similique saepe maxime culpa sit? Ducimus
            adipisci perferendis commodi. Voluptatibus quam sit, debitis odit recusandae cupiditate, asperiores nisi sint distinctio nulla autem possimus esse nostrum deserunt. Voluptatum nemo sint delectus consequatur, ipsum mollitia. Debitis aliquam
            consectetur repudiandae commodi ratione est sit inventore aliquid nam blanditiis aperiam distinctio doloremque nihil sed quae voluptatum cum modi, eveniet alias voluptas harum unde. Hic libero error eveniet saepe ab animi laborum adipisci
            magnam eos incidunt minus, odio molestiae. Debitis cum molestiae reiciendis ipsa. Error nemo ipsum eius explicabo accusantium dolore, voluptatibus et quos laboriosam maxime eum saepe. Exercitationem nam natus delectus placeat doloribus sunt
            consequatur autem sapiente. Architecto obcaecati quis reiciendis repellat recusandae sequi exercitationem rerum. Ipsa, mollitia. Ipsam, quas, officia voluptatibus repudiandae, eaque eos quis sit voluptas fugiat quae laudantium adipisci tempora
            ullam magnam dolorem delectus! Natus alias distinctio deserunt laboriosam placeat doloremque vel quis possimus, laudantium accusantium? Consectetur recusandae eaque voluptas eligendi modi vel ratione libero aperiam rem! Sint qui reprehenderit
            ut, adipisci tenetur minus cumque, iusto quam id quis harum exercitationem aspernatur sit rem eius nobis libero a nam animi laborum esse accusamus illo provident dolor. Repudiandae, aliquam. Et illum itaque eum beatae facilis nihil nam? Voluptatibus
            nesciunt veritatis voluptate facere autem molestiae ut similique deserunt eligendi odit! Eius error sit ut praesentium voluptate eum ullam modi architecto, sequi quae. Error obcaecati ducimus debitis ratione nam saepe omnis tempore excepturi
            natus ex exercitationem necessitatibus minus, minima a ipsa ad repellat placeat ipsam culpa sequi dicta. Ea rem tenetur quibusdam illum magni perferendis saepe quasi quisquam, odio amet adipisci, voluptate repellat voluptates impedit facilis
            expedita aliquam velit officiis! Nemo maxime illo sapiente omnis corporis iusto sunt similique enim beatae itaque quasi pariatur, voluptas impedit consequuntur ipsam iste delectus unde? Sunt, ipsam quasi. Debitis veniam laborum modi sequi
            accusantium ut fugit reprehenderit rem hic laudantium aperiam illo nulla odit officiis, saepe, architecto voluptas, nam eos iste aliquid vel! Vero dolorem nemo amet eaque fuga illum, sed fugiat, ullam quo iste facere voluptates!</p>
        </div>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: okay, I'll try this and let you know.
thankyou