# Element.scrollTop always return 0

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, slick.js

I need to detect whether user scroll to the bottom of the HTML element. I know that best way to do that is use:

```
obj.scrollTop === (obj.scrollHeight - obj.offsetHeight)
```

But the problem is that in my case, `obj.scrollTop` always returns 0. It's probably something wrong with my CSS or with the fact that I use `slick` library, but I can't find what it could be.

Here's my parent component:

```
<div className="container container--light container--player">
    <Header menu="dark" />
    <main className="player">
        <div className="scrollCarousel">
            <Slider ref={slider} {...settings}>
                <PlayerSlide1 />
                <PlayerSlide2 />
                <PlayerFAQ ref={faqContainer} />
            </Slider>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

And child component HTML:

```
<section className="faq scrollCarousel__slide" ref={ref}>
        ... some inner HTML
</section>
```

I want to detect whether user scroll to the bottom of my child component (with class `faq`).

Here's my CSS:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh
}

.player {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.scrollCarousel {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 75vh;
}

.scrollCarousel__slide {
    width: calc(var(--siteWidthNarrow) - 20px);
    margin: auto;
    background: transparent;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 70vh;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 177px);
    overflow-x: visible;
}

.faq {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `obj`? Cant you just use [`document.scrollingElement.scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/scrollingElement)?

Comment: I just post it as an example, in my code I use `faqContainer.current.scrollTop`, but it's not what cause the error here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [element.scrollTop always returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391907/element-scrolltop-always-returns-0)

Comment: Unfortunately no, I already tried to remove `height: 100vh;` from my container and it doesn't work. The fact that `inner` doesn't have a scrollbar is also not the issue - my element has scrollbar (`overflow: scroll;` for `.faq`).

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden; //maybe this causes the issue, once you set overflow hidden, then you should set min-height 100vh
    position: relative;
}
```

things like:

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height:100vh;
    position: relative;
}
```